# Unity Calculating HDR Color's Intensity From RGB Values

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am now currently working on a project which players will be able to customize the colors of some materials. The materials use HDR colors and I have post processing bloom effect on my scene.

So I want the players to be able to change the intensity of the color to determine which objects glow and others don't.

I made a custom slider-input field mixed UI control to change this. But the problem is I can't set the intensity for this with the RGB values of the colors at the start of the scene.

Is there any formula to find the intensity of the color with RGB values?

Answer (score 0):

HDR (High Dynamic Range) color representation uses a different approach than traditional RGB (Red, Green, Blue) color representation. In HDR, the intensity of a color is represented using a floating-point value, rather than an integer value like in RGB. This allows for a much larger range of intensities to be represented, resulting in a more subtle and nuanced color representation.

To calculate the intensity of an HDR color from RGB values, we need to use a technique called "tone mapping." Tone mapping is a process that maps the wide range of intensity values found in HDR images to a narrower range of intensity values that can be displayed on a traditional monitor or display device.

There are many tone mapping algorithms available, but one common method is to use a logarithmic function to compress the intensity values of the HDR image while preserving the relative differences between them. The compressed intensity values can then be converted to RGB values using a transfer function that maps the compressed intensity values to the final RGB values.

Here's a simplified example of how this might work:

Start with an HDR image represented as a 3D array of float values (red, green, blue, alpha), where each pixel has a value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.
Apply a tone mapping algorithm to the HDR image, which compresses the intensity values while preserving the relative differences between them. One common tone mapping algorithm is the Reinhard tone mapping algorithm, which applies a logarithmic compression to the intensity values:
new_color = max(0.0, min(1.0, pow(color, 1.0 / 2.2)))

This formula takes the original color value, raises it to the power of 1.0 / 2.2 (which is approximately 0.75), and then clamps the result to the range of 0.0 to 1.0. This reduces the overall range of intensity values while preserving the relative differences between them.
3. Convert the compressed intensity values to RGB values using a transfer function. The transfer function maps the compressed intensity values to the final RGB values, taking into account the display device's color space and gamma correction. A simple example of a transfer function is a linear interpolation between two endpoints:

RGB = (intensity * (endpoint2 - endpoint1)) + endpoint1

Where endpoint1 and endpoint2 represent the minimum and maximum intensity values that the display device can produce, respectively.

By applying these steps, we can convert an HDR color representation to an RGB color representation that can be displayed on a traditional monitor or display device. However, note that this is just a simplified example, and there are many variations and optimizations of this process depending on the specific requirements of the application.

Comment: I got a much longer response than I expected. Is there any quick formula which I can code? Or must I make a research about HDR colors and mapping algorithms?

Comment: sqrt( 0.299*R^2 + 0.587*G^2 + 0.114*B^2 )

Comment: this formula has some problem. I will send correct formula next week. and can you send me demo project or screenshot. Because i don't know about your project.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work properly. But I don't think any demo or screenshot is needed. I just need to get the intensity value. That is the only problem. If I had the formula the system wouldn't have any problems.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: ...and are you aware of [our policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)?